# Create a graph using Mathematica and Python

Tags: python, csv, wolfram-mathematica

I was wondering how I would go about using Python to create a Graph with Mathematica. I want to be able to use python code to invoke mathematica to create a new graph, using data from a CSV file.

Comment: Here's some hints: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+mathematica These may not be precisely what you want.  But you could try using Google for additional resources.

Comment: Do you mean a graph as in [graph theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory) or a graph as in [a plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_of_a_function) of some data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old fashioned way to do [what Yaroslav suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466217/create-a-graph-using-mathematica-and-python/4467260#4467260) is to just call the kernel ([math](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/program/math.html)) with the script switch e.g. `math -script graph.m`. Where `graph.m` is either constructed beforehand and will load the csv file or is constructed on the fly by your python program.

Can I ask why you want to use Mathematica for making the graph? There are lots of python (and other) utilities that will do it for you. There are lots of options listed here: [graph survey](http://wiki.sagemath.org/graph_survey#PythonLibraries).

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to look at [PYML](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/585/), which provides a Python API for Mathematica.

Depending on your needs, you might also want to look at [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/) which would allow you to do the graphing in Python.

Comment: I would also go the matplotlib route.

Answer (score 2):

You could make a Mathematica [shell script](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-8/mathematica-shell-scripts/) and call it from Python using `os.system()`